# Kotlin external annotations for JDK are not set

Tags: kotlin

I have an Android project in IntelliJ. The Android module isn't using Kotlin. I have a Java module that I thought I'd try some Kotlin out with.

A very annoying error keeps popping up. "Kotlin external annotations for JDK are not set". I'll do whatever it wants me to do. I just want the error to go away.

Does anyone know where to configure Kotlin External Annotations for the JDK?

Comment: If you mean a yellow balloon in the IDE, then there's a clickable action link in it that fixes the problem.

Comment: I do mean that, and I click it, and nothing happens. It just keeps popping up every time I build.

Comment: Looks like an unpleasant bug in the IDE. Could you report it to the [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/KT) to be investigated by our team?

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is very frustrating. While I don't know actually how to satisfy Kotlin's desire for the annotations, you can disable the popups in Android Studio.

Go to Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications. Find the "Kotlin External Annotations" group and change it from its default of "Sticky Balloon". You can make it "Balloon" which times out or "No Popup" to disable entirely.

[image: Disabling Kotlin External Annotation Popups in Android Studio]